# How to make each user's information directory inside of each user's directory in firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to make a flutter app where if the user is logged in and uploads an image of a specific challenge, the uploaded image is inside of the challenge folder, and that challenge folder is inside of the user folder(named with the user's name), and that user folder is inside of a folder called 'users' in my firebase console.

I basically developed an authentication protocol that the user can sign up or log in to my app using their own email(It's not like a google authentication though, just submitting their email account and password).

But I can't really tell where to start to develop the protocol that I've mentioned above.

Comment: Why don't you use the user's email as a unique id?

Comment: Actually, there's a user uid for each user though. But like I said, I have no idea where to start to develop the structure of the directory that I have explained :(

Comment: Here's the github link to my team's repository. Just in case for any questions that you would might have :)

https://github.com/Solved-Earth/Solved.Earth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite easy. You need to create a [`Reference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference-class.html) as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/create-reference#create_a_reference), based on the path you describe in your question:

```
String userIdentifier = '...';  // E.g. the user ID or the user email, it all depends on your authentication mechanism
String imageName = '...'; 

final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
final userImageRef = storageRef.child("users/" + userIdentifier + "/challenge/" + imageName);
```

Then, with this `Reference` you upload the image file as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files) in the doc.

Note that the `userIdentifier` and `imageName` values should not contain a slash (`/`)